# no POLLHUP event when poll on tcp socket and remote closed

Tags: c, linux

I want to use poll() to monitor the tcp socket session end event.

```
struct pollfd pollfd = {0};
pollfd.fd = fd;
pollfd.events = 0;

poll(&pollfd, 1, -1);
```

but no any event when remote closed, poll() blocked. if I `poll()` POLLIN event, I will get it, and `read()` return 0. why no `POLLHUP` event when remote closed.

the code I used in my project should be right, the above code is just a demo.

Comment: First of all, are you sure you want to use a timeout of `0`? That means `poll` will return *immediately*, and if there's no HUP event waiting when you call `poll` then there's no event for you to get. Perhaps you should use a negative number to wait for an event to arrive?

Comment: Then what do `poll` itself return? It doesn't fail (and return `-1`)? What, if any, events are set in `pollfd.revents`?

Comment: Given `struct pollfd pollfd;`, what do you do to make sure the structure isn't populated with garbage?  Please post a *complete* example.  And what do you think `pollfd.events = 0;` means?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The code is just a demo, I correct it

Comment: @AndrewHenle as the manual of poll(), events can be 0, to monitor POLLHUP/POLLERR/POLLINV.

Comment: I did some wireshark sniffer. I found that when other peer close the socket. it just send a FIN, so the tcp is half closed. if I shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR) in my side. the tcp is full closed, then I can see the HUP and both POLLIN in my poll(). it seems POLLHUP is not usefull, I should use POLLIN instead.